# Change Data Range in Excel Line Chart using Apache POI

Tags: java, charts, apache-poi, xssf

I am trying to see if it is possible to change the data range of a series in a line chart using Apache POI.

I am able to pull the series from the chart itself, but cannot find a method that allows me to change the data range.

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook("C:\\Workbook.xlsx");
Sheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFDrawing drawing = (XSSFDrawing) worksheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
List<XSSFChart> charts = drawing.getCharts();
for (XSSFChart chart : charts) {
    String title = chart.getTitleText().toString();
    if (title.equals("Z-Acceleration")) {
        CTChart cc = chart.getCTChart();
        CTPlotArea plotArea = cc.getPlotArea();
        CTLineSer[] ccc = plotArea.getLineChartArray()[0].getSerArray();
        for (CTLineSer s : ccc) {
            System.out.println(s.xmlText());
        }
        System.out.println(ccc.length);
    }
}
```

I printed out the XML text to see if it was indeed able to pull the series from the chart correctly and was able to find its title and data range, but no way to change it.

Comment: You have the `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTLineSer`, so of course you would be able to change it. But you needs to know what to change (what is the meaning of the `XML`) and how to change (download the source of [ooxml-schemas](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas) and do `javadoc` from it to get an `API` documentation). But why not using the new `XDDF` stuff of `apache poi 4.1.0` instead of trying it that way?

Comment: @AxelRichter I realized that I was still using 3.17 and just made the change. However, I have already tried to download the soure for the ooxml-schemas and only had the compiled class files with no javadocs.

Comment: From http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.3/ download `ooxml-schemas-1.3-sources.jar`. Unzip that. Then go to directory `ooxml-schemas-1.3` and do `javadoc -d javadoc -sourcepath ./ -subpackages org`. After that you find the `API`docs in `ooxml-schemas-1.3/javadoc`. Start with `overview-tree.html`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, since this is a good question at all, let's have a concrete example of how to change data range in Excel line chart using `apache poi`.

Let's start with following sheet:

[image]

Then the following code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.SpreadsheetVersion;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.util.List;

class ExcelChangeChartDataSource {

 static XSSFChart getChartWithTitle(XSSFSheet sheet, String wantedTitle) {
  if (sheet == null || wantedTitle == null) return null;
  XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
  List<XSSFChart> charts = drawing.getCharts();
  for (XSSFChart chart : charts) {
   String title = chart.getTitleText().toString();
   if (wantedTitle.equals(title)) return chart;
  }
  return null;
 }

 static void addMonthDataToChart(XSSFSheet sheet, XSSFChart chart, String month, Double[] seriesData) {
  CTChart ctChart = chart.getCTChart();
  CTPlotArea ctPlotArea = ctChart.getPlotArea();
  List<CTLineSer> ctLineSerList = ctPlotArea.getLineChartArray(0).getSerList();

  Row row;
  Cell cell;
  int ser = 0;
  for (CTLineSer ctLineSer : ctLineSerList) {

   CTAxDataSource cttAxDataSource = ctLineSer.getCat();
   CTStrRef ctStrRef = cttAxDataSource.getStrRef();

   AreaReference catReference = new AreaReference(ctStrRef.getF(), SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
   CellReference firstCatCell = catReference.getFirstCell();
   CellReference lastCatCell = catReference.getLastCell();
   if (firstCatCell.getCol() == lastCatCell.getCol()) {
    int col = firstCatCell.getCol();
    int lastRow = lastCatCell.getRow();
    row = sheet.getRow(lastRow+1); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(lastRow+1);
    cell = row.getCell(col); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(col);
    cell.setCellValue(month);

    ctStrRef.setF(new AreaReference(
                  firstCatCell, 
                  new CellReference(lastCatCell.getSheetName(), lastRow+1, col, true, true), 
                  SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007).formatAsString()
                 );

    CTNumDataSource ctNumDataSource = ctLineSer.getVal();
    CTNumRef ctNumRef = ctNumDataSource.getNumRef();

    AreaReference numReference = new AreaReference(ctNumRef.getF(), SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
    CellReference firstNumCell = numReference.getFirstCell();
    CellReference lastNumCell = numReference.getLastCell();
    if (lastNumCell.getRow() == lastRow && firstNumCell.getCol() == lastNumCell.getCol()) {
     col = firstNumCell.getCol();
     row = sheet.getRow(lastRow+1); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(lastRow+1);
     cell = row.getCell(col); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(col);
     if (ser < seriesData.length) cell.setCellValue(seriesData[ser]);

     ctNumRef.setF(new AreaReference(
                   firstNumCell, 
                   new CellReference(lastNumCell.getSheetName(), lastRow+1, col, true, true), 
                   SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007).formatAsString()
                  );
    }
   }
   ser++;
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("WorkbookWithChart.xlsx"));

  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  XSSFChart chart = getChartWithTitle(sheet, "Z-Acceleration"); 

  if (chart != null) {
   addMonthDataToChart(sheet, chart, "Apr", new Double[]{7d,3d,5d});
   addMonthDataToChart(sheet, chart, "Mai", new Double[]{2d,6d,8d});
   addMonthDataToChart(sheet, chart, "Jun", new Double[]{1d,9d,4d});
   addMonthDataToChart(sheet, chart, "Jul", new Double[]{5d,6d});
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("WorkbookWithChartNew.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

produces following result:

[image]

This code uses `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.*` classes and can be used with `apache poi 3.17` as well as with `apache poi 4.1.0`.

Unfortunately there is not any `API` documentation of `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.*` public available. So if we need it, we need to download `ooxml-schemas-1.3-sources.jar` from [central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.3](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.3/). Then unzip that. Then go to directory `ooxml-schemas-1.3` and do `javadoc -d javadoc -sourcepath ./ -subpackages org`. After that we find the `API` docs in `ooxml-schemas-1.3/javadoc`. Start reading with `overview-tree.html`.

For `apache poi 4.1.0` we need `ooxml-schemas-1.4`.

I have tried the same using the new `XDDF` stuff in `apache poi 4.1.0` too. But at first the code is not really much less expensive and at second this has the disadvantage that `XDDFChart.plot` fails when some data in `XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> values` are not present. Then we would must set those data points 0. But this is not the same as not present. So using the new `XDDF`stuff in this case is not really a progress. But nevertheless, here is the code, i have tried:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.SpreadsheetVersion;

import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.util.List;

class ExcelChangeChartDataSource {

 static XSSFChart getChartWithTitle(XSSFSheet sheet, String wantedTitle) {
  if (sheet == null || wantedTitle == null) return null;
  XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
  List<XSSFChart> charts = drawing.getCharts();
  for (XSSFChart chart : charts) {
   String title = chart.getTitleText().toString();
   if (wantedTitle.equals(title)) return chart;
  }
  return null;
 }

 static void addMonthDataToChart(XSSFSheet sheet, XSSFChart chart, String month, Double[] seriesData) {
  Row row;
  Cell cell;

  List<XDDFChartData> chartDataList = chart.getChartSeries();
  XDDFChartData chartData = chartDataList.get(0);

  List<XDDFChartData.Series> seriesList = chartData.getSeries();
  int ser = 0;
  for (XDDFChartData.Series series : seriesList) {
   XDDFDataSource categoryData = series.getCategoryData();
   AreaReference catReference = new AreaReference(categoryData.getDataRangeReference(), SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
   CellReference firstCatCell = catReference.getFirstCell();
   CellReference lastCatCell = catReference.getLastCell();
   if (firstCatCell.getCol() == lastCatCell.getCol()) {
    int col = firstCatCell.getCol();
    int lastRow = lastCatCell.getRow();
    row = sheet.getRow(lastRow+1); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(lastRow+1);
    cell = row.getCell(col); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(col);
    cell.setCellValue(month);

    XDDFDataSource<String> category = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(
                                       sheet, 
                                       new CellRangeAddress(firstCatCell.getRow(), lastRow+1, col, col));

    XDDFNumericalDataSource valuesData = series.getValuesData();
    AreaReference numReference = new AreaReference(valuesData.getDataRangeReference(), SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
    CellReference firstNumCell = numReference.getFirstCell();
    CellReference lastNumCell = numReference.getLastCell();
    if (lastNumCell.getRow() == lastRow && firstNumCell.getCol() == lastNumCell.getCol()) {
     col = firstNumCell.getCol();
     row = sheet.getRow(lastRow+1); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(lastRow+1);
     cell = row.getCell(col); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(col);
     if (ser < seriesData.length) cell.setCellValue(seriesData[ser]);
     else cell.setCellValue(0); // Here we need set 0 where it not should be needed.

     XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> values = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(
                                               sheet, 
                                               new CellRangeAddress(firstNumCell.getRow(), lastRow+1, col, col));

     series.replaceData(category, values);
    }
   }
   ser++;
  }
  chart.plot(chartData);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("WorkbookWithChart.xlsx"));

  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  XSSFChart chart = getChartWithTitle(sheet, "Z-Acceleration"); 

  if (chart != null) {
   addMonthDataToChart(sheet, chart, "Apr", new Double[]{7d,3d,5d});
   addMonthDataToChart(sheet, chart, "Mai", new Double[]{2d,6d,8d});
   addMonthDataToChart(sheet, chart, "Jun", new Double[]{1d,9d,4d});
   addMonthDataToChart(sheet, chart, "Jul", new Double[]{5d,6d});
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("WorkbookWithChartNew.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: One of the most elaborate and useful answers I've found in a few years being here. Thanks, Axel.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding new rows, you can remove data from the chart display by setting the row height to zero.

First, create the chart with largest possible data range, like the following.
[image]

Then, use the following code to set the rows that you don't want to see in the graph with height zero.

```
    for(int i=8;i<14;i++) {
        sheet.getRow(i).setZeroHeight(true);;
    }
```

And now you will see the output Excel changed to the following.

[image]

By the way, you can also update the graph title by linking it to a cell value, like the example above, with the graph title linked to cell A1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If using NPOI (C#) to update the datasource of a line chart, you have to do the following:

1. Access and update the range for the category (horizontal axis)
2. Access and update the range for each of the series.

###### Procedure:

1. You have to locate the chart.  You can do this by iterating the charts on a sheet, and checking for the chart title.

   1.a. You get the collection of charts (XSSFChart objects) by calling CreateDrawingPatriarch() on the sheet, casting it to (NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFDrawing), then calling GetCharts() on that.

   1.b. Iterate over the chart collection looking, checking the .Title property.

   1.c. Once you have the XSSFChart object, use the GetCTChart() method to get the CT_Chart object from it.
2. Get the Plot area of the chart using the .plotArea property of the CT_Chart object.
3. Now get the collection of CT_LineChart objects by calling the .lineChart property on the plotArea.  For a Bar Chart call the .barChart property.
4. For each CT_LineChart object, call the .ser property to get a collection of  CT_LineSer objects.  For Bar Charts you get a collection of CT_BarSer objects.

   You will have one ser object (CT_LineSer or CT_BarSer) for each series.
5. You can read the series name, using this procedure:

   5.a  From the .tx property of the ser object, get the .strRef property.  From there the .f property will have the address of where the series name is stored.  See below on how to read the text at that address.
6. To get or set the range for the Category (axis horizontal labels):

   6.a  Access the .cat property of the ser, and the the .strRef property of the cat.  From there the .f property will have the range of the category.  The .f property is read/write, so you can set it to change the range.  If the .strRef property is null, then look at the .numRef property instead.  It depends on whether the values of the category are text of numeric.  Dates are numeric, for instance.

   It may be counterintuitive that each ser has it's own category, but that's how the data is stored.
7. To get or set the range of the series:

   7.a  Access the .val property of the ser, and the the .numRef property of the val.  From there the .f property will have the range of the series.  The .f property is read/write, so you can set it to change the range.

##### Helpers:

###### How to read a cell value given a reference address:

1. Create a cell reference from the address by instantiating NPOI.SS.Util.CellReference and passing the address in the constructor.  From the cell reference you can obtain the sheet name and the numeric row and column values.
2. Get the sheet name from the cell reference by calling the .SheetName property.
3. Get the sheet object by passing the sheet name to the GetSheet() method of the workbook.
4. Get the IRow object by calling GetRow on the sheet, passing in the .Row property of the cell reference.
5. Get the ICell object by calling GetCell on the IRow, passing in the .Col property of the cell reference.
6. To get the value of the cell, use the .StringCellValue property of the ICell object.

###### How to work with a range address:

1. Given a reference that's a full range such as "Sheet1!$C$5:$C$11", to get the various parts, pass the reference to constructor of an NPOI.SS.Util.AreaReference object.
2. You can also construct an AreaReference using individual parts, and then get back the full reference by using the FormatAsString() method.