# How to modify a graph label in apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Right now, I'm trying to modify the following labels from **an existing .xlsx**

Graph Image:
[image: Graph Image]

The graph is already modified their formulas and values for the ones I want, but those numbers are still getting their value from previous values in the graph. How can I change them? I was looking for previous questions, and supposedly the method to use to **get the current label values (before modifying them)** would be the following one:

```
drawing.getCharts().get(0).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartList().get(0).getSerList().get(2).getVal().getNumRef().getNumCache()
```

The drawing obtained is the following one from my sheet:

```
 XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
```

But I get a list with 107 values... So I'm not sure if it's correct or not. I don't know what do I need to modify. I would appreciate some help please.

Minimal example about how did I modify the graph:

This excel sheet has five seriesList with a formula based on other excel sheets. So I did the following code:

```
 drawing.getCharts().get(0).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartList().get(0).getSerList().get(0).getVal().getNumRef().setF("PERD_POLICY!$S$15:$S$" + lineasPerdPolicy + "");
    drawing.getCharts().get(0).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartList().get(0).getSerList().get(0).getCat().getNumRef().setF("PERD_POLICY!$Q$15:$Q$" + lineasPerdPolicy);

    drawing.getCharts().get(0).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartList().get(0).getSerList().get(1).getVal().getNumRef().setF("PERD_POLICY!$T$15:$T$" + lineasPerdPolicy);      
    drawing.getCharts().get(0).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartList().get(0).getSerList().get(1).getCat().getNumRef().setF("PERD_POLICY!$Q$15:$Q$" + lineasPerdPolicy);

    drawing.getCharts().get(0).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartList().get(0).getSerList().get(2).getVal().getNumRef().setF("PERD_POLICY!$U$15:$U$" + lineasPerdPolicy);
    drawing.getCharts().get(0).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartList().get(0).getSerList().get(2).getCat().getNumRef().setF("PERD_POLICY!$Q$15:$Q$" + lineasPerdPolicy);

    drawing.getCharts().get(0).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartList().get(0).getSerList().get(3).getVal().getNumRef().setF("PERD_POLICY!$V$15:$V$" + lineasPerdPolicy);
    drawing.getCharts().get(0).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartList().get(0).getSerList().get(3).getCat().getNumRef().setF("PERD_POLICY!$Q$15:$Q$" + lineasPerdPolicy);

    drawing.getCharts().get(0).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartList().get(0).getSerList().get(4).getVal().getNumRef().setF("PERD_POLICY!$W$15:$W$" + lineasPerdPolicy);
    drawing.getCharts().get(0).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartList().get(0).getSerList().get(4).getCat().getNumRef().setF("PERD_POLICY!$Q$15:$Q$" + lineasPerdPolicy);

    drawing.getCharts().get(0).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartList().get(0).getSerList().get(5).getVal().getNumRef().setF("PERD_POLICY!$R$15:$R$" + lineasPerdPolicy);
    drawing.getCharts().get(0).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartList().get(0).getSerList().get(5).getCat().getNumRef().setF("PERD_POLICY!$Q$15:$Q$" + lineasPerdPolicy);
```

lineasPerdPolicy is a variable I used to count the last row in the sheet we are getting the values from. The sheet "PERD_POLICY" . This graph is based on months from years. I added now to the current serList a new value, until December 2019. But the last label of the green chart, is showing 9,66. That value is from October 2019.

I think you will get it better with the following images. This one shows what is the value of the last label:

[The current label value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMAAx.png)

And the selected value in this other picture is the one I want to show in the label, **9,75**

[The graph value I want to show in the label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3NLh.png)

If you don't understand any word please let me know, because my excel is in spanish.
Valor --> Value
Punto --> Point

Comment: Chart data labels show the values of the chart's data basis. So if you say "The graph is already modified their formulas and values for the ones I want." then this is not done correctly and the data basis has not changed correctly. Please show how you have done this in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi! I modified my question. Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code using the low level `ooxml-schemas` classes only updates the reference formulas of the series. It does not update the cached values in the chart.

Since the current `apache poi 4.1.1` provides [XDDFChartData.Series.replaceData](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChartData.Series.html#replaceData-org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSource-org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFNumericalDataSource-) to update the chart's data, we should use this instead of the low level `ooxml-schemas` classes.

Let's have a complete example to show how to do this.

We start having a `ExcelWithChartMar.xlsx` looking like so:

[image]

As you see there are the chart data in `A1:D4` for months Jan to Mar already and a chart showing those data.

What we need to know: The first data row is 1 (row 0 is header row) and the current last data row is 3. The last data row will increase. The category column is 0 (`A`) and the series columns are 1 (`B`),2 (`C`) and 3 (`D`). Note, all indexes are 0 based.

Now we can run the following code using `apache poi 4.1.1`:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;

class ExcelChangeChartData {

 static void updateChartData(XSSFChart chart, XSSFSheet dataSheet, 
  int firstDataRow, int lastDataRow, int categoryColumn, int[] seriesColumns) {

  for (XDDFChartData chartData : chart.getChartSeries()) {
   for (int s = 0; s < chartData.getSeriesCount() ; s++) {
    XDDFChartData.Series series = chartData.getSeries(s);
    if (seriesColumns.length > s) {
     XDDFCategoryDataSource category = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(
      dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(firstDataRow, lastDataRow, categoryColumn, categoryColumn));
     int seriesColumn = seriesColumns[s];
     XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> values = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(
      dataSheet, new CellRangeAddress(firstDataRow, lastDataRow, seriesColumn, seriesColumn));
     series.replaceData(category, values);  
     series.plot();
    }
   }
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String[] months = new String[]{"Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
  int firstDataRow = 1;
  int lastDataRow = 3;
  int categoryColumn = 0;
  int[] seriesColumns = new int[]{1,2,3};

  for (int m = 0; m < months.length - 1; m++) {
   String monthSource = months[m];
   String monthResult = months[m+1];
   String filePath = "./ExcelWithChart" + monthSource + ".xlsx";
   java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();
   XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filePath));
   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
   XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(lastDataRow + 1);
   XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(categoryColumn);
   cell.setCellValue(monthResult);
   for (int i = 0; i < seriesColumns.length; i++) {
    cell = row.createCell(seriesColumns[i]);
    cell.setCellValue(random.nextDouble() / 10 + 0.02);
    cell.setCellStyle(sheet.getRow(lastDataRow).getCell(seriesColumns[i]).getCellStyle());
   }
   lastDataRow++;

   XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
   XSSFChart chart = drawing.getCharts().get(0);
   updateChartData(chart, sheet, firstDataRow, lastDataRow, categoryColumn, seriesColumns);

   filePath = "./ExcelWithChart" + monthResult + ".xlsx";
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
   workbook.write(out);
   out.close();
   workbook.close();
  }
 }
}
```

This creates 9 additional `Excel` files `ExcelWithChartApr.xlsx` ... `ExcelWithChartDec.xlsx` where each has a new month's data added.

The method `updateChartData` updates the chart data using the `XDDFChartData.Series.replaceData` method.

Comment: Hi Axel! 
First, thanks for such an extended example. I'm having a nullPointerException when I'm trying to access to the chartSeries like this:

drawing.getCharts().get(0).getChartSeries()

Is this caused because of the Excel I'm trying to read or I'm readint it wrongly...? And there's no other way to change it using low level ooxl-´schemas?

By the way, printing drawing.getCharts().get(0) shows this:

Name: /xl/charts/chart1.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawingml.chart+xml

(Drawing.getCharts size is 1)

Comment: @Sergio García: Your comment about the `NPE` does not make much sense. If `drawing.getCharts().get(0)` returns a chart and prints `Name: /xl/charts/chart1.xml...` as you said, then `drawing.getCharts().get(0).getChartSeries()` cannot throw `NPE`. And of course all this also is possible oly using low level `ooxml-schemas` classes. But this is very tedious and needs to much code to show here in detail.

Comment: I know it may sound weird... but it's happening and I don't know if it's because how it's created the .xlsx I'm reading or...? This is the error (run by a JUNit test):

https://imgur.com/a/SseaFeG

Comment: @Sergio García: According to your stack trace in the linked picture, it fails to get the charts data from it's data source. This occurs if there is no category source in chart's data source. In my example it occurs if the range `A1:A4` (month names) is not within the chart's data range. Simply do changing your template accordingly. There must be data available for the catagory axis.

Comment: Note that the procedure for the using the NPOI version of this is significantly different.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77760709/75129